# Unity 2 property injection, how do I translate config to fluent syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, unity-container

I have a httpHandler and using Unity 2 I would like to inject a dependency into my HttpHandler.

My code looks like:

```
public class MyHandler : BaseHandler
{

    public MyHandler()
    {
    }

    public IConfigurationManager Configuration
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    ...
}
```

Using the web.config I would configure it like this (left out the rest of the config for simplicity) :

```
<type type="MyHandler">
   <typeConfig extensionType="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.TypeInjectionElement, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration">
      <property name="Configuration" propertyType="IConfigurationManager">
        <dependency/>
      </property>
   </typeConfig>
</type>
```

How would I go about doing the same thing using fluent syntax? Everything I have tried so far leaves the property set to null when the handler fires.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to call the `ConfigureInjectionFor` method.

```
myContainer.Configure<InjectedMembers>()
    .ConfigureInjectionFor<MyHandler>(
            new InjectionProperty("Configuration", 
                                  new ResolvedParameter<IConfigurationManager>())
                                 )
            )
```

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of Handler factory. It allow you to create your handler

```
 class HandlerFactory : IHttpHandlerFactory
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHandler(HttpContext context, string requestType, String url, String pathTranslated)
        {
            return MyContainerProvider.Container.Resolve<MyHandler>();
        }
        public void ReleaseHandler(IHttpHandler handler)
        {
        }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
```

Then, you have to register the factory in your web application (to allow IIS to find it). You can find more details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227439(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Onof, for some reason this does not work for me. I even tried the [Dependency] attribute on the Configuration property. Injection inside controllers seem to work just fine but I can't get it to work inside a httphandler with Unity.

Comment: This is enough to configure the container. You need to build up the handler, for example registering an HttpHandlerFactory

Comment: Onof, do you have an example of this? And also, why do I have to build up the handler? This is fairly new to me so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

ConfigureInjectionFor has been obsolete since Unity 1.2 was released.

This should work:

```
container.RegisterType<MyHandler>(
    new InjectionProperty("Configuration"));
```